# Android button enabling/disabling not working

Tags: android

I need to disable a button based on one parameter present month . Here is my code

```
 if(presentMonth > 20)
 {
     nextMonth.setClickable(false);
     nextMonth.setOnClickListener(null);
 }
 else
 {
    nextMonth.setOnClickListener(new MyListener());
 }
```

Where nextMonth is the Button name, I tried setEnabled , setClickable and  setOnClickListener(null), but the button is not disabled. Is there anything, I am missing here.

Comment: setEnabled(false) for disable and true for enable

Comment: Are you sure about "Enable/disable" or you want to show/hide button?

Comment: If you tried setEnabled , setClickable and setOnClickListener(null), then can you check presentMonth value. May be that is always greater than 20.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. It happens because I was calling its in OnCreate which will be called only once for the first time. And in the first time ,it got the listener, then after this code was never used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the methods should work,cause they are meant for that. `setEnabled()`
and yes I have used one other way I remember that like

```
onClick(View v)
{
     if(!condition)
     {
            //perform onClick stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: Hai man, i tried exactly like this, it works. For me, the problem was i was doing it in onCreate and onCreate is called only once.So the listener got registered for Button

Comment: The Android has provided the methods for enabling and disabling the click of button..setClickable..I advice you to do some more work on finding the real problem why that didn't work for you..when you get time..for now..CHEEERRSSS..!!

Comment: @njzk2 You are most welcome in advance to make edit on answer in sense of making it better.

Answer (score 1):

try, `nextMonth.setEnabled(false)`. Normally clickable property is set in the XML layout such as `android:clickable="true`