# Disabling touchlistener  working in one context but not in another context

Tags: android

i have an application which has this [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZCjg.jpg). now when the user touches some button and releases his finger from that button, the key is entered into the textbox. mean while it also pronounces that letter to the user. saying "B is entered". so it is during ACTION_UP. during this event handling  i need to prevent touch events even if by accident the user touches them.

i am disabling the touchlistener during touch events(in UP state), but it is not happening.The touch events are getting queued and i am not getting how to disable the touch event while the current one is being handled.but i could able to accomplish it during the hardkeys event handling. i could not understand this weird behavior.

here is my code

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = null;

```
    s = ((Button) v).getText().toString().trim();

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {


    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        b_prev=(Button)v;
        //while(tts.isSpeaking());
        tts.speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        fun(false);  //disabling the touch event for all buttons


        for(int i=0;i<mybtn.length;i++)
        {
            if(isPointInsideView(event.getRawX(),event.getRawY(),mybtn[i]))
            {
                s = (mybtn[i]).getText().toString().trim();
                btn=mybtn[i];
                break;
              //et.setText("up android" + s, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            }
        }

        if(btn.equals(mybtn[27])) //clear button pressed
        {
            //do something
        }

        else if(btn.equals(mybtn[26])) //space button
        {
            //do soemthing

        }

        else
        {
          //do soemthing
        }


        fun(true); //enabling touch event for all buttons


        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        for(int i=0;i<mybtn.length;i++)
        {
            if(isPointInsideView(event.getRawX(),event.getRawY(),mybtn[i]))
            {
                s = (mybtn[i]).getText().toString().trim();
                btn=mybtn[i];
                break;
              //et.setText("down android" + s, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

            }
        }


        break; 


    }


    return true;
}

void fun(boolean flag)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<mybtn.length;i++)
    {
        if(flag==true)
        mybtn[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
        else
            mybtn[i].setOnTouchListener(null);  
        mybtn[i].setEnabled(flag);
    }

}
```

Even though i am disabling the touch events using fun(), they are getting queued and executing after the completion of current touch event. so please tell me what i need to do to fix this problem.

i have made an observation that i am using two hardkeys in confirmation events.during hard key events the disabling/enabling of layout buttons is working fine. But it is not working same in the above scenario. what could be the problem with it? i am attaching that code as well. look at it.why this is happening i am not getting.

public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {

```
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
    {
        String s = et.getText().toString().trim();

        fun(false); //disable touch events

        if(pass==1 && quit==1)
        {
            name= et.getText().toString().trim();
            number=get_Number(name);

            if(number!=null)
            {
                pass++; // go for confirmation
                in = new Intent(ContactActivity.this, Calling.class);
                tts.speak("contact found", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                while(tts.isSpeaking());
                tts.speak("Do u want to continue", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                while(tts.isSpeaking());

            }

            else
            { 
                tts.speak( name +"does not exist", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                while(tts.isSpeaking());
                tts.speak("try again", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                while(tts.isSpeaking());

                fun(true); //enable touch events

            }


        }

        else if(pass==2)
        {

            b.putString("number", number);
            in.putExtras(b);
            tts.speak( "calling"+name, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            while(tts.isSpeaking());
            tts.shutdown();
            startActivity(in);
            //int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
            //android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
            finish();

            //Intent 

        }

        else if (quit==2) {

            while(tts.isSpeaking());
            tts.speak("Quitting application",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

           while(tts.isSpeaking());
            tts.shutdown();
            finish();

            }


    }//end of if


    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
    {

        fun(false);//disable touch events

        if(pass==2)
        {

            pass=1;
            //while(tts.isSpeaking());
            tts.speak("Going back",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            while(tts.isSpeaking());
            fun(true);
            //mhandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1000);

        }

        else if(quit==2)
        {
            quit=1;
            //while(tts.isSpeaking());
            tts.speak("Going back",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            while(tts.isSpeaking());

            fun(true);//enable touch events

        }

        else if(quit==1)
        {
            quit++;
            //mhandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            //while(tts.isSpeaking());
            tts.speak("Do u want to quit",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            while(tts.isSpeaking());
            //Toast.makeText(TimerActivity.this,"Do u want to quit",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }


    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: somebody please help me out, i have googled a lot and tried in different  ways.but still i could not get a clear idea of how to fix this problem....

Comment: Guys please help me out to solve this problem. i have tried it a lot still no use, i am not getting where it is going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Try the workaround mentioned here [Android button enabling/disabling not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046471/android-button-enabling-disabling-not-working)

```
onClick(View v)
{
     if(condition)
     {
           return;
     }
     else
     {
       //perform onClick stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: no yaar, it is not at all solution to my problem.i am handling touch events and that to it has so many states like DOWN, MOVE and UP. the fun() function should actually do the job. but it is not doing, i am not getting what to do and how to work it out

Comment: BTW it is not a good practice to disable a button just so that you can process an input, i would suggest not disabling any request and queuing them up and processing them one by one in a separate thread

Comment: i did not get u. i want to block the touch event till the time UP event is not done.after it is done,i want to reenable the touch event

Comment: Why do you want to block it till your UP event processing is done? In the meanwhile, maybe the user has pressed something else? The best practice is to not block anything but queue it up for processing!

Comment: please see my edited post, i am developing an app for blind. so while the input processing taking place during UP event, it should pronounce it to user saying that "C is entered".meanwhile if the user touches another key, it should as well pronounce that letter to user using TTS, but it leads to a clash, so i want to disable  touch to prevent that clash. got my point??

Comment: i have one more problem, can u help me with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598673/how-to-block-current-activity-till-the-tts-engine-is-not-initialized. when i start TTS engine checking using some intent, mean while i am saying something. so i want to block my main activity till TTS is not initialized. can u help me with that??